# Unable to install "gpustat" on a virtualenv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

python==3.6.12
Trying to install gpustat using `pip3 install gpustat` after activating the env.

Comment: What is the error that you get when try to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have root privilege. Try this:
`pip install --user gpustat`

References: [GitHub: gpustat](https://github.com/wookayin/gpustat/)